# Is Rails 3 removing Metal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, gridfs

Is Rails 3 removing Metal?

I am trying to implement Mongoid, Carrierwave and grid_fs.

I have followed [guide 1](http://socialmemorycomplex.net/2010/06/02/gridfs-with-mongoid-and-carrierwave-on-rails-3/).

However, I have read that Rails 3 is removing Metal ( http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ed34652d1aca148fea61c5309c1bd5ff3a55abfa ).

So I stumbled across this article instead: [guide 2](http://antekpiechnik.com/posts/setting-up-carrierwave-file-uploads-using-gridfs-on-rails-3-and-mongoid)

Given the circumstances that Rails 3 may be removing Metal and for future maintenance. Which guide is more suitable to get grid_fs, Mongoid and Carrierwave all working together?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You noticed a commit with the comment "Removing Metal from Rails 3." However, what is going on is actually quite the *opposite* of that phrase!

Rails 3 did not *remove* metal. Quite the opposite. Now, [*all* controllers are metals](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/rails-and-merb-merge-plugin-api-part-3-of-6/), with only those additional features that you request. All you need to do is inherit your particular controller class from `ActionController::Metal`, and then `include` any particular modules that provide the additional features you want in that particular controller.

Of course, most people will inherit their controllers from `ActionController::Base`. But now, `ActionController::Base` merely inherits `ActionController::Metal` and includes all of the additional feature modules.

That commit you noticed is removing metals as a *separate* feature, apart from the rest of `ActionPack`. Now, metals are no longer a *separate* feature, so the *separate feature implementation* of metals was removed. Now, *everything* is a metal.

Comment: Thanks for for clarifying that